# java wait for dialog to be closed

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

i have a small program where an element is draged and dropped, when the drop is performed i open a dialog (extends Jframe) where some text should be entered. The Problem is, that i want to wait for this dialog to be closed (actually the  ok button to be pressed so i can read out the data from the textfield), than analyse what the user has entered and based on that i will decide if the drop is rejected or allowed.

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
      try{
            //popup

            Popup p = new Popup();
            p.setParmeter("enter a new name: ");
            p.setVisible(true);

            //programm wont wait before the user has pressed ok in the popup 
            System.out.println("value: " + p.getValue());

            repaint();

        } else {
            e.rejectDrop();
        }
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Popup is a dialog extended from a JFrame. The problem is, that p.getValue() is executed before the User gets to press the ok button. I tried using a boolean variable and a loop to check if something was entered in the popup but it doesnt work, the dialog is desplayed but there is not textfield or ok button, so the only thing i can do is to kill it. I'm pretty new to gui's so i really would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible you should re-implement `Popup` to inherit from `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`, and call `JDialog`'s `setModal(true)` method, which will prevent subsequent code from running until the dialog is dismissed.

Alternatively, check out the static convenience methods in [`JOptionPane`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), which eliminate the need to implement your own bespoke dialog class in many cases.  For example (from the `JOptionPane` API):

*Show an information panel with the options yes/no and message 'choose one':*

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "choose one", "choose one", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: Sir can you tell me how to dismissed the dialog when a ok button is pressed or when cancel is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Java has built-in dialog support. Yon don't want to extend JFrame. See the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) on how to make dialogs.